# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' ... i did npm install firebase but it kept showing me these errors

Tags: reactjs

Here is the fire base auth db config

```
import firebase from "firebase"; 


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCpJGllufwimbMsNpEmj0bZwxOWd6jUqbU",
    authDomain: "clone-d2c4e.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "clone-d2c4e",
    storageBucket: "clone-d2c4e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "22204566405",
    appId: "1:22204566405:web:0216e3001c7b8f449292ec",
    measurementId: "G-67SZW8Q96B"
  }; 

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
const db = firebaseApp.firestore(); 
const auth = firebase.auth(); 


export {db, auth} ;
```

Comment: Your title says *it kept showing me these errors*, but your post does not include even a single error. Please [edit] your post to more clearly describe the problem, include the **complete, exact error messages**, and ask a specific question related to the code you posted. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before you begin posting (as was suggested when you created your account here, but you chose to ignore).

Comment: try adding after importing firebase `import "firebase/firestore`